# Application has stopped in react Native

Tags: react-native

Respect every one, when i run my app in react native then the following error occur , help me to avoid this error.

> Task :app:installDebug
>   10:55:00 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
>   10:55:01 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>   10:55:01 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_3_API_16-jelly(AVD) - 4.1.2' for app:debug
>   10:55:01 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   10:55:01 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   10:55:01 D/ddms: Reading file permision of E:\My Final Year Project\Home_Pages\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
>   10:55:01 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
>   10:55:04 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>   10:55:04 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   10:55:04 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
>   10:55:04 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>   10:55:04 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Comment: Did you try to install this one real device ?

Comment: Try to clean gradle and re run

Comment: Akila Devinda i m not run it on real device except emulator, but this error occur when package  install the app in emulator..........